# Simulate a phone call in Android emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to implement a overlay screen over the default system screen when phone rings. I want to receive a broadcastreceiver in my emulator for a phone call. How can I simulate the phone call?

Comment: Edit your question to state what emulator (iPhone?  Android? ??) and it might be reopened.

Comment: Android Emulator in Eclipse. Sorry, I am new to android. Any help is appreciated

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#console and then http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#telephony

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris :)...I am now able to emulate a phone call